# Shiny server: socket hang up

Tags: r, node.js, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

*Update: I added the solution below*

## The problem

A little background: I am running Shiny server v1.5 on an Ubuntu precise server. Basically I have an rmarkdown page that allows the user to play with some parameters and then has a download button that generates a document using shiny like so:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
downloadHandler(
  filename = "report.pdf",
  content = function(file) {
    knitr::knit2pdf("report.Rnw",envir=environment())
    file.rename(normalizePath('report.pdf'), file)
  }
)
```
````

The Shiny application works fine on my local machine, but crashes on the server.  More specifically, the r markdown webpage works fine, but once I click the download button, the app crashes after about 30 seconds. The server logs indicate a socket time-out error:

```
[2016-02-24 03:38:52.240] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
[2016-02-24 03:49:30.183] [ERROR] shiny-server - Uncaught exception: Error: socket hang up
[2016-02-24 03:49:30.184] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:247:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)
[2016-02-24 03:49:30.184] [INFO] shiny-server - Stopping listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
[2016-02-24 03:49:30.185] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes (with notification)
/opt/shiny-server/lib/main.js:364
  throw err;
        ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:247:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)
```

This pdf takes quite a long time to generate (about five minutes), so I'm suspecting that I missed some time-out parameter somewhere. This is what I did in my shiny configuration:

```
run_as shiny;
app_init_timeout 999999;
app_idle_timeout 999999;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;
  ....
}
```

... but to no avail, because I'm still getting the error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

## The solution

As mentioned by @daattali, you cannot have something take that long inside downloadButton, changing the server settings will not change anything about that. So I ended up splitting the generation & download functionality in two parts like so:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "!$('makeReport').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
          actionButton("makeReport","Generate Report",icon=icon("file"))
        )
      ),
      column(4,
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "!$('makeReport').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
        uiOutput("downloadButton")
        #downloadButton("downloadReport", "Download Report")
      )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$download_button <- renderUI({
        downloadButton("downloadReport", "Download Results")
     })
    makeReportAction <- eventReactive(input$makeReport, {
        ...
        knitr::knit2pdf("report.Rnw",envir=globalenv())
    })
    output$downloadButton <- renderUI({
      makeReportAction() #only appear after first click on generate
      downloadButton("downloadReport", "Download Report")
    })
    output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        cat(paste("Does the pdf exist?",file.exists("report.pdf")))
        file.rename(normalizePath('report.pdf'), file)
      }
    )
  }
)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the same problem someone else asked Joe Cheng about in the Google board last week

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/4bL9jFaYly0

It looks like there's a time limit on the download handler, so maybe try seeing if it's possible to generate the file beforehand and only serving the file when the button is clicked